# Не могу найти ошибку в скрипте

Tags: javascript

Всего лишь вторую неделю изучаю Основы программирования. 
Есть задача, надо решить с помощью JavaScript'a.
Сижу второй день, туплю (
Перепробывал массу вариантов, результат так и не появился (
Помогите плиз куда смотреть, на что обратить внимание

Определить все четырехзначные числа, сумма цифр которых равна их произведению.

```
a=1; b=0; c=0; d=0; // числа
n=0; // количество чисел

for(a=1,b=0,c=0,d=0;a<=9,b<=9,c<=9,d<=9;a++,b++,c++,d++)
    if(a+b+c+d == a*b*c*d)
    k=1000*a+100*b+10*c+d;
    n+=1;
    document.write("четырехзначные числа "+n);
```

Comment: Вот эта запись: `for(a=1,b=0,c=0,d=0;a<=9,b<=9,c<=9,d<=9;a++,b++,c++,d++)` делает совсем не то, что Вы, видимо, ожидаете.

Comment: Алексей, да, существует. У меня даже есть ответ, т.к. в инете нашел пример программы на Паскале http://109informatika.at.ua/Uroki/8_klass/urok_43.html

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в определении цикла:

```
for(a=1,b=0,c=0,d=0;a<=9,b<=9,c<=9,d<=9;a++,b++,c++,d++)
```

в этом случае переменные на каждой итерации будут меняться **одновременно**, таким образом будет всего 8 итераций.

Кроме того, чтобы в теле цикла выполнилось несколько операций, его нужно обернуть в фигурные скобки, иначе внутри цикла будет выполнена только первая, в данном случае

```
if(a+b+c+d == a*b*c*d)
    k=1000*a+100*b+10*c+d;
```

Чтобы выбранный подход заработал, нужно **4** цикла:

```js
var n = 0,
  nums = [];
for (a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
  for (b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
    for (c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
      for (d = 0; d <= 9; d++) {
        if (a + b + c + d == a * b * c * d) {
          k = 1000 * a + 100 * b + 10 * c + d;
          n += 1;
          nums.push(k);
        }
      }
document.write("четырехзначные числа " + n);
document.write('<br>', JSON.stringify(nums));
```

Но можно пойти с другой стороны: перебрать *в одном* цикле все четырехзначные числа, и уже внутри проверять подходит число или нет.

Например так:

```js
var n = 0,
  nums = [];
for (var i = 1000; i < 10000; i++) {
  if (i.toString().split('').reduce((a, b) => +b + a, 0) == i.toString().split('').reduce((a, b) => +b * a, 1)) {
    n += 1;
    nums.push(i);
  }
}
document.write("четырехзначные числа " + n);
document.write('<br>', JSON.stringify(nums));
```